# Getting error when compressing file with ZipFile

Tags: c#, zip

I am using Windows form application. In my application I am using `FolderBrowserDialog`, `textbox1` and two buttons. In my textbox I am passing folder. From folder it will select particular file type. After getting such file type I need to convert it using ZipFile i.e. Iconic.zip. After retrieving particular file type it is showing me error of FileNotfound. For testing purpose I tried to display retrived file to listbox and it is working well. But when I am calling via ZipFile it is giving me error, can't figure out what error is.

```
namespace WinDataStore
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;         
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {                
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;              
               Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                //notification to user
                return;
            }

            string[] extensions = { ".xml",".ddg" };

            string[] dizin = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
          //  listBox1.Items.AddRange(dizin);
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddFile("dizin", "files");

                zip.Save("z.zip");
            }        


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `"dizin"`? I guess, you were going to add an array, but not a file named `dizin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code solved my problem
      using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
               foreach(var file in dizin)
                {
                   zip.AddFile(file);
                }
                zip.Save("z.zip");
            }

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a variable as a string like this:

```
string[] dizin = ...;
zip.AddFile("dizin", "files");
```

Instead use it like this:

```
zip.AddFile(dizin, "files");
```

Or more likely you need to loop:

```
foreach(var file in dizin)
{
    zip.AddFile(file, "files");
}
```

Or if you are using `Ionic Zip Library` use the [`AddFiles`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/007fac8a-e77e-f558-41e4-572d47946c33.htm) method:

```
zip.AddFiles(dizin, "files");
```

Comment: foreach(var file in dizin)
{
    zip.AddFile(file, "files");
} creating the zip file but not including retrieved file